# Grouping and sorting boxes (ndarray of coordinates)

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, sorting

I have a multidimensional numpy array holding four points (coordinates) representing a box:

> [startX,startY], [endX,startY], [endX,endY], [startX, endY]

An example:

```
[[[298.      404.     ]
  [354.      404.     ]
  [354.      430.     ]
  [298.      430.     ]]

 [[358.      404.     ]
  [416.      404.     ]
  [416.      428.     ]
  [358.      428.     ]]

 [[136.      406.     ]
  [190.      406.     ]
  [190.      428.     ]
  [136.      428.     ]]

 [[194.      406.     ]
  [246.      406.     ]
  [246.      430.     ]
  [194.      430.     ]]

 [[422.49792 403.28558]
  [505.2563  408.01465]
  [503.85352 432.56305]
  [421.09515 427.83398]]

 [[246.68146 410.22128]
  [291.68146 407.22128]
  [293.1947  429.92038]
  [248.1947  432.92038]]

 [[234.      436.     ]
  [296.      436.     ]
  [296.      460.     ]
  [234.      460.     ]]

 [[298.      436.     ]
  [342.      436.     ]
  [342.      462.     ]
  [298.      462.     ]]

 [[343.37756 438.08197]
  [455.64294 434.57367]
  [456.55414 463.73267]
  [344.28876 467.24097]]

 [[186.      440.     ]
  [230.      440.     ]
  [230.      464.     ]
  [186.      464.     ]]]
```

Since each box is representing the position of a word in an image I want to sort these boxes in the way they would be read. Starting top-left and ending bottom-right.
I was thinking about sorting the boxes by their startY value with:

```
box_group = box_group[np.argsort(box_group[:, 0, 1])]
```

This works fine. Now I have to group each box that overlaps another one in height into one line. I check this with:

```
def isOnSameLine(boxOne, boxTwo):
    boxOneStartY = boxOne[0,1]
    boxOneEndY = boxOne[2,1]
    boxTwoStartY = boxTwo[0,1]
    boxTwoEndY = boxTwo[2,1]
    if((boxTwoStartY < boxOneEndY and boxTwoStartY > boxOneStartY)
    or(boxTwoEndY < boxOneEndY and boxTwoEndY > boxOneStartY)):
        return True
    else:
        return False
```

Having the grouped boxes which are on one line I can sort them by their startX value and should be done. But I have no clue how to iterate over all boxes and group/sort them in lines while doing so. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

This will do.

```
def isOnSameLine(boxOne, boxTwo):
    boxOneStartY = boxOne[0,1]
    boxOneEndY = boxOne[2,1]
    boxTwoStartY = boxTwo[0,1]
    boxTwoEndY = boxTwo[2,1]
    if((boxTwoStartY <= boxOneEndY and boxTwoStartY >= boxOneStartY)
    or(boxTwoEndY <= boxOneEndY and boxTwoEndY >= boxOneStartY)
    or(boxTwoEndY >= boxOneEndY and boxTwoStartY <= boxOneStartY)):
        return True
    else:
        return False

# list of indexes
temp = []
i = 0

# TODO: check if there is more than one box_group
while i < len(box_group):
    for j in range(i + 1, len(box_group)):
        if(isOnSameLine(box_group[i],box_group[j])):
            print(str(i) + " and " + str(j) + " on same line")
            if i not in temp:
                temp.append(i)
            if j not in temp:
                temp.append(j)
        else:
            print(str(i) + " and " + str(j) + " not on same line")
        # append temp with i if the current box (i) is not on the same line with any other box
        if len(temp) == 0:
            temp.append(i)

    # put boxes on same line into lined_box_group array
    lined_box_group = box_group[np.array(temp)]
    # sort boxes by startX value
    lined_box_group = lined_box_group[np.argsort(lined_box_group[:, 0, 0])]
    # copy sorted boxes on same line into sorted_box_group
    sorted_box_group[i:temp[-1]+1] = lined_box_group

    # skip to the index of the box that is not on the same line
    i = temp[-1] + 1
    # clear list of indexes
    temp = []
```

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like lexsort might be all you need (maybe with x/y reversed):

```
startY = boxes[:, 0, 1]
startX = boxes[:, 0, 0]
order = np.lexsort([startY, startX])
```